# Replacing every occurrence of an element in a list, only when it follows a specified element

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, lisp

I am trying to write a function `replaceAfter(A X Y L)` that replaces every occurrence of X with Y in L, only when X comes after A.

Example:

`replaceAfter d m t '(f d s d m p m h d m u m) -> '(f d s d t p m h m t u m)`

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
(define replaceAfter
    (lambda(A X Y L)
        (cond
            ( (null? L)          '() )
            ( (if (and (equal? (car L) A) (equal? (car (cdr L)) X) ) (cons (cons (car L) Y) (replaceAfter A X Y (cdr (cdr L))))) )
            (#t (cons (car L) (relaceAfter A X Y (cdr L))))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: There is actually no question here. What do you want to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most easily achieved with a sub-procedure that does the iteration, progressively consuming list `l` while building the result list. Using `cons` instead of `append` is not only a performance improvement, but has also the positive effect that the first element of the result list is the previous element that needs to be compared to `a`:

```
(define replace-after
  (lambda (a x y l)
    ; ---- sub procedure  
    (define iter
      (lambda (lst result)
        (if (null? lst)
            (reverse result)
            (let ((current (car lst)))
              (iter (cdr lst)
                    (cons (if (and (not (null? result))    ; there is a previous element
                                   (equal? (car result) a) ; previous is a
                                   (equal? current x))     ; current is x
                              y
                              current)
                          result))))))
    ; call iter
    (iter l '())))
```

Of course you'll need to reverse the result at the very end but this is the canonical way to proceed in Scheme.

If you add a little `display` statement you'll see how it works:

```
> (replace-after 'd 'm 't '(f d s d m p m h d m u m))
lst (f d s d m p m h d m u m)  - result ()
lst (d s d m p m h d m u m)  - result (f)
lst (s d m p m h d m u m)  - result (d f)
lst (d m p m h d m u m)  - result (s d f)
lst (m p m h d m u m)  - result (d s d f)
lst (p m h d m u m)  - result (t d s d f)
lst (m h d m u m)  - result (p t d s d f)
lst (h d m u m)  - result (m p t d s d f)
lst (d m u m)  - result (h m p t d s d f)
lst (m u m)  - result (d h m p t d s d f)
lst (u m)  - result (t d h m p t d s d f)
lst (m)  - result (u t d h m p t d s d f)
lst ()  - result (m u t d h m p t d s d f)
'(f d s d t p m h d t u m)
```

Note that the result differs from the one you wrote in your question but I believe this one is correct.

The only case that is not clear from your specs is the following:

```
> (replace-after 'd 'm 'd '(d m m))
lst (d m m)  - result ()
lst (m m)  - result (d)
lst (m)  - result (d d)
lst ()  - result (d d d)
'(d d d)
```

Should this actually return `'(d d d)` or rather `(d d m)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
(define replace-after
  (lambda (d m t lst)
    (let loop ((todo lst)
               (done '())
               (replace #f))
      (if (null? todo)
          (reverse done)
          (let ((item (car todo)))
            (loop (cdr todo)
                  (cons (if (and replace (eq? m item)) t item) done)
                  (eq? item d)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove that `IF` from the second branch. Also, those two `CONS`es are currently making a list like `((1 . 2) . 3)` rather than `(1 . (2 . 3))`.

```
(define (replace-after a x y l)
  (cond 
    ((< (length l) 2) l)
    ((and (equal? (car l) a)
          (equal? (cadr l) x))
     (cons (car l) (cons y (replace-after a x y (cddr l)))))
    (else (cons (car l) (replace-after a x y (cdr l))))))
```

Comment: Try to evaluate `(replace-after 'a 'b 'c '(b a))`.